# Why my button not work correctly? SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2, audio-player

I try to make little program with SDL2 and C++. There is a window and button on window. I want to do that when I press first time the button music starts to play. Yeah I made it work.

```
            if((mouseX >= buttonRect.x && mouseX < (buttonRect.x + buttonRect.w)) && (mouseY >= buttonRect.y && mouseY < (buttonRect.y + buttonRect.h))){
                if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)){
                    if(Mix_PlayingMusic() == 0){
                        Mix_PlayMusic(music, -1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I want to make that when button is pressed second time music would pause. And if it will pressed again it resume.

I tried this:

```
            if((mouseX >= buttonRect.x && mouseX < (buttonRect.x + buttonRect.w)) && (mouseY >= buttonRect.y && mouseY < (buttonRect.y + buttonRect.h))){
                if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)){
                    if(Mix_PlayingMusic() == 0){
                        Mix_PlayMusic(music, -1);
                    }else{
                        if(Mix_PausedMusic() == 1){
                            Mix_ResumeMusic();
                        }else{
                            Mix_PauseMusic();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But it won't work. When I press the button music starts and stops instantly. If If I hold mouse button down on the button music will play, but if I move mouse it stops.

Answer (score 0):

Mix_PlayMusic returns 0 on success, or -1 on errors.
Try defining static variable to follow state of the player;

```
            if((mouseX >= buttonRect.x && mouseX < (buttonRect.x + buttonRect.w)) && (mouseY >= buttonRect.y && mouseY < (buttonRect.y + buttonRect.h))){
                static int STATE = 0; // not played
                if(event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)){
                    if(STATE == 0){
                        Mix_PlayMusic(music, -1);
                        STATE = 1; // playing music
                    }else{
                        if(STATE == 2){
                            Mix_ResumeMusic();
                        } else {
                            Mix_PauseMusic();
                            STATE = 2; // paused
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```